# $\mathbb{Z}$ homeomorphic to $X=\left\{ 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},... \right\}$?

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb{Z}$ homeomorphic to $X=\left\{ 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},... \right\}$? (Each set is equipped with the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$)

I would assume that the answer is yes, since they are both discrete (so every subset is open) and have the same cardinality. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Yes, this is sufficient. - But why?

Comment: Since they have the same cardinality there exists a bijection between them. And surely the preimage of any open set under this bijection will be open (since every subset is open). Is this true?

Comment: A topological space with discrete topology caries no more information than a set, so constructing a homeomorphism between two such discrete spaces is the same as just finding a bijection.

Comment: Open sets in topology are an abstraction of the notion of *nearness* on the real line, but in a discrete space, every point is an island.

Comment: yes, all of the above is right. It is enough to just know there is a bijection, but just for fun I will write down explicitly one possible such bijection $f:\Bbb Z\to X$. Let $f(0)=1$, $f(n)=\frac1{2n}$ if $n>0$, and  $f(n)=\frac1{-2n+1}$ if $n<0$. So, e.g. $0\to1$, $1\to1/2$, $-1\to1/3$, $2\to1/4$, $-2\to1/5$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Z$ and $X$ have the same cardinality, there exists a bijective map $f : X \to \mathbb Z$.

Since both $X$ and $\mathbb Z$ have the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb R$ (with the standard topology), they are both discrete.

$f$ and $f^{-1}$ are open maps since they take singletons to open sets, and every open set can be written as a union of singletons.